# Determine all x in which the functions are differentiable

Tags: analysis, derivatives

$(a) \ I:=(0,\infty) \text{ and } f(x):=\frac{e^{2^x}x^2}{log(1+x)}$

$(b) \ I:=\mathbb{R} \text{ and } f(x):=e^{\frac{1}{e^{1+x^2}}}$

$(c) \ I:=\mathbb{R} \text{ and } f(x):=
\begin{cases} 
      x^3+x+\frac{1}{2} & x\in(-\infty, 0) \\
      \frac{1}{2}(1+x) & x\in[0,1) \\
      1+\log(\sqrt{x}) & x\in[1,\infty)
   \end{cases}$

Can someone please show me how to determine all x in which the functions are differentiable.

Best regards

Comment: '..I've managed to calculate the derivatives...' You should've written what you have done up to that point.

Comment: I've changed the description of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a theorem that sums, products, and compositions of differentiable functions are differentiable.  That sufficies for a and b once you rule out the possibility of division by zero.  For c it also suffices except at the points where you change from one expression to another.  You need to evaluate the limit of the function as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left and right, then evaluate the limit of the derivative as $x$ approaches $0$.  If each of these matches across the joint the function is differentiable there.  Then do the same at $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The possibility of division by zero for (a) is already ruled out by $I:=(0,\infty)$, right? Only log(1)=0 and x is always > 0.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should say that in your answer.

Comment: If $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\infty$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=-\infty$, I can conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, right?